# Copy rows filtered on a search criteria from one table to another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, copy, filtering

Using MySQL, I want to retrieve all rows from a table A where a field contains "EQ" for example, copy them into table B (which has exactly the same field), and then delete them from table A.

I heard about triggers. Is that the right approach?

Comment: which db you are using

Comment: I'm using mysql

Comment: Please include the table schemas. This can be accomplished by: `DESCRIBE 
 my_table_name;`.

Comment: I think you should actually delete this question and work with a tutorial first, like https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp then write a specific question based on issues adapting the example to your own purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need 2 SQL statements. First for inserting the data rows from A to B, and then for deleting those rows from A.

   ```
   INSERT  INTO B
   SELECT  *
   FROM    A
   WHERE   Field LIKE '%EQ%';

   DELETE  
   FROM    A
   WHERE   Field LIKE '%EQ%';
   ```
2. Triggers are a way to automate some activities when some other activity in a separate table happens. If you need to make sure that the above 2 operations should be triggered as soon someone INSERTS/DELETES/UPDATES on some other table, then you can create a trigger for that purpose. But with the simple requirement you gave above without any such dependency, I do not see a need of a trigger here.

If you do have such dependency and need, you have to provide proper requirements with details here.

Comment: Thanks you for your help!
What if my table B is the same as A, with one field added ? Does the insert match field names, and my field added will be null ?

Comment: The above statement would work only because you said both A and B have exact same table structure. If you have mismatch in number of columns, you have specify the column names to which you want to insert in the insert statement. Eg. INSERT INTO B (Col1, Col2, Col3) SELECT Col1 = Col1, Col2 = Col6, Col3 = Col7 FROM A;

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation here for a thorough understanding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @san He is using MySQL not SQL Server, although he doesn't state it in the question as originally written.